# GO VS code extension installation not successful

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I've installed VS code GO extension. However, the intellisense isn't working as few of the GO extensions related tools doesn't seem to be working.

I get this error.

[image]

When I click on "Install" for 1st one i.e. "go-outline", i get below error:
[image]

Then I  try t install gopls by clicking on the "Install" button in the prmpt but again i get this error like below:
[image]

Is it something to do with proxy issue. If yes,how do i fix it.
Or why isn't GO lang extension installing properly on my system.

I tried on bpth windows & linux systems. Its the same issue.

Comment: Please try setting proxy in Vscode settings.json with this line "http.proxy": "http://proxy-address:proxy-port"

Comment: install all pkg on terminal for example `go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` if not work use VPN, this not bug. sometime happen to me i change network or use VPN.